# How to use libruby.so built with rbenv for gvim?

Tags: rbenv

I installed `gvim` via `pacman` (a package manager used in `Arch Linux`) without official `ruby` package, then `gvim` does not work:

```
# pacman -S --dbonly ruby
# pacman -S gvim
$ gvim
gvim: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ ldd `which gvim` | grep ruby
  libruby.so.2.2 => not found
```

I have used `rbenv` to manage my `ruby` environment and `libruby.so.2.2` is located at `$HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/`. The library was created with `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared"` option when `ruby 2.2.0` was installed.

So, how can I let `gvim` know where the library path is? It would be ideal if the change will also be reflected when I change my `ruby` version via `rbenv global`.